# iOS: How to navigate from DetailView to DetailView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, ios4, detailview

I am looking into SimpleDrillDown sample for iOS on Apple Developer website: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Introduction/Intro.html

There is a UITableView and when user selects item we navigate to DetailView.

Now, I would like to be able to click on the item in DetailView and open a new DetailView for that item and populate with corresponding content.

Basically, how can one navigate from DetailView to DetailView?

Comment: What have u tried? Any code will help to answer u perfectly.

Comment: I'm really just learning now. I'll post code if I'll run into issues. Thanks for asking though!

Answer (score 2):

There is no 1:1 relationship between viewcontrollers. 
In ios navigation controller, there is a root view controller and others are detail view controllers.

Once you push a view controller, you can then push other view controllers from within that view.

A stack of all view controllers is maintained in navigation controller.

U can push a view controller using

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:ctrl animated:YES];`

And then you can pop a view controller using

`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Also to go to a particular view in stack you can use

```
 [self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

And to return to root view controller

```
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new DetailView in the DetailView and push it.